# Calling UpdateWindow() from a secondary thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, mfc

I have a windows application for displaying very complex vector graphics. Since the drawing take a while to complete, I moved the rendering logic to a separate thread.

The relevant code snippet is given below. Here CCanvas is derived from `CWnd` and `m_MemDC` is CDC pointer to draw the all graphics. The `OnPaint()` handler bitblts this memdc contents to PaintDC.

In the Render() method, once the image drawing is completed I have to update the display window. Here I am calling the `Invalidate()` and `UpdateWindow()` methods directly. Is this safe to call these methods from a secondary thread?

```
void CCanvas::UpdateDisplay()
{
    ::SetEvent(m_hRenderWaitEvent);
}

DWORD WINAPI RenderThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    CCanvas* pThis = static_cast<CCanvas*>(lpParam);
    pThis->Render();

    return 0;
}

void CCanvas::Render()
{
    HANDLE hEvents[] = {m_hStopEvent, m_hRenderWaitEvent};
    while (true)
    {
        switch (WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE))
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0:
            return;
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
            Draw(&m_MemDC);
            Invalidate();
            UpdateWindow();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void CCanvas::Draw( CDC* pDC )
{
    //Image drawing logic here
}

void CCanvas::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc( this );

    CRect rctClient;
    GetClientRect( rctClient );
    dc.BitBlt( rctClient.left, rctClient.top, rctClient.Width(), rctClient.Height(), &m_MemDC, rctClient.left, rctClient.top, SRCCOPY );
}
```

Comment: Hi, If memory serves me correctly I experienced occasional non-catchable crashes a tearing doing things that way.  It's a bit temperamental and might have you handing out 'It Works On My Machine' stickers :0  
I'd recommend using double-buffering and passing a thread-safe object with your paint data to the painter thread. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe to call GUI functions on a thread other than the thread that created the Window.

I would create a custom message to post from the background thread when the image is ready. The main thread can then handle this in the normal message loop to redraw the window.

Note: you will need to ensure that the mechanism you use for the background rendering is correctly synchronized: e.g. use a mutex around access to your `m_MemDC` to avoid having the background thread trying to update it while the foreground thread is reading it to paint the UI.

I would actually recommend have *two* paint buffers. One that is being used as the render target, and one that is read by the `WM_PAINT` handler. When rendering is complete, the render thread can lock the mutex, swap the buffers, unlock the mutex and post the message. The `WM_PAINT` handler can lock the mutex, copy from the active buffer to the window, and unlock the mutex. This means the render thread is only ever blocking the message-handling thread for the time it takes to swap the "active buffer" marker, rather than the whole render time if `WM_PAINT` gets called for any other reason (e.g. your window is covered/uncovered, or resized, or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK (and I can remember), Windows UI is not guaranteed to be thread safe. Calling any UI function from a thread that is not the thread processing the event loop is known to cause trouble.

The correct way is either to post a message to the main event loop, or to make the loop use `MessageWaitForMultipleEvents` instead of the simple `GetMessage` to allow the background threads to send any event to the foreground thread.